# PWA breake the orientation in one view

Tags: javascript, css, progressive-web-apps, html-framework-7, manifest.json

My app working in most views with the portrait orientation, last with the line on the manifest file

```
​​"orientation": "portrait"
```

So, only in one view, I have to break with this rule and allow to rotate landscape orientation if the user want

How can I do that?

Regards.

Answer (score 1):

What we ended up doing is removing "orientation" property completely from manifest.json. That would allow full screen video with rotations. I guess if you really want to leave only "portrait" orientation in the rest of the app, you can lock it with JS using the `screen.orientation` API: https://caniuse.com/#feat=screen-orientation (81.82% supported):

```
// to lock portrait
ScreenOrientation.lock("portrait");

// and then allow any
ScreenOrientation.unlock();
```

Please note, that this is still a working draft, not a live spec. Some more [docs and info from Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ScreenOrientation/lock).

Comment: hi, thanks for your comments, I have gotten an error when used the API (Chrome browser) Uncaught TypeError: ScreenOrientation.lock is not a function